# Firestore creating a representation of a order form

Tags: date, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new at firebase/firestore. Appreciate your thoughts on this.

I'm trying to create an order form using Firestore.

I was wondering:

1. Do I need to create a YEAR, MONTH, DATE of collections and documents just to save all the order forms ?

   This felt redundant to me, otherwise a lot of databases in Firestore will require a lot of collections and documents of dates!

   E.g.:

   > (CAPS is Collection, bracketed are the documents)
   >      YEAR (2018) -> MONTH (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc)
   >      JAN -> 1 (order #1, order #2, order #3, etc)
   >      JAN -> 2 (order #1, order #2, etc...)
2. Or just a simple time stamp on each document of order form - and then if I want to look up say for the month of January, is there a search query to look up all the documents in a specific month? or date?
3. And as order forms go, the user can enter as many items as possible. Is it correct to have each item stored as a new document? Therefore possibly creating 100+ documents per collection of order form.

   E.g.:

   > order 1 collection - banana document, apple document, orange document

Comment: You can do with ServerValue.Timestamp for ordering the data and then populate according to that. And its is good idea to create Multiple documents because each document has a limit.

Comment: Using ServerValue.Timestamp as one of the unique key, say if I want to search for orders done in January, does Firestore have a way to search by the month?

Comment: @HWong You cannot use the server-side timestamp as a key/document id. It is only usable as a *value*.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks understood!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single best data model. It all depends on the use-cases of your app. For a general introduction to this domain, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

But in Firestore having a collection with many documents is not a concern. The database was made to scale to almost any number of documents.

You'll indeed want to store a timestamp in each order. The best way for this is like to use a [server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects). You can then query for orders in a given date range with a query like this:

```
var now = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60*1000);
ordersRef.where("timestamp", ">=", yesterday).where("timestamp", "<=", now)
```

Or

```
ordersRef.where("timestamp", ">=", "2017-01-01").where("timestamp", "<=", "2017-12-31")
```

For more examples, see the [Firestore documentation on queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

Comment: Thanks! I'll study your document on NoSQL a bit more. As you probably figured, I am from the ancient days of MySQL, just trying out some Android programming.